# bash 'declare' can not be used in a script?

Tags: bash, emacs

I have some bash functions defined in my `.bashrc' file.  In emacs
shell-mode, I want to use  complete the function names.

The emacs `shell' package can not complete the functions by default, so I
plan to enhance it.

The problem is I can not get current function definitions of the shell.  The
usual way to query the function definitions is to type:

```
   $ declare -F
```

Since the 'declare' is just a built-in command, we should wrap it in a
script file then invoke it with `bash'.  With emacs we can:

```
   * create a file, wrap the code:

     -------------- file: get-functions -----------

     declare -F

     -------------- file end ----------------------

   * in emacs, eval the expression:

     (call-process "bash" "get-functions" "output-buffer")
```

But, I get nothing in the `output-buffer'.  The interesting thing is, if I
run the script in a real shell:

```
  $ bash get-functions
```

I still get nothing output.

Does this mean that we can not use `declare -F' in a script?

**By the way, if we remove the "-F" option from the script file, then we can
get output when invoke "bash get-functions", but what we get is not function
definitions, but is all the variables.**

My environment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu), CentOS 6.3 32bits

Comment: There is already a package which adds completion of builtins/aliases/functions, etc. within shell-mode: https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion .

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution yet, just to check if "declare -F" works:

```
(shell)
(comint-send-string (get-buffer-process "*shell*") "declare -F")
(comint-send-string (get-buffer-process "*shell*") "\n")
(switch-to-buffer "*shell*")
```

Comment: This just like you type "declare -F" in the inferior shell buffer.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head I would guess this has to do with functions not being exported (and bash cannot currently export functions).
In other words: You have to source your functions.

...it is possible you could work around this by using a login shell too, but off the bat sourcing seems easier to me.

Comment: The functions is written in the login shell's rc file.  That means the functions have been already sourced.

Comment: Apparently they are not sourced - they are not inherited :)
You can try by adding a simple '. ~/.bashrc' at the top of your script.